g++ compiler error: undefined reference to `std::__throw_bad_array_new_length()
I am building a program which implement kD-Tree and kNN by C++, the dataset using mnist. When I compiled the program using command:
g++ -o main main.cpp kDTree.cpp Dataset.o -I . -std=c++11
g++ version 10.3
The error showed that
E:\C_plus_code\init> g++ -o main main.cpp kDTree.cpp  Dataset.o -I . -std=c++11
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dataset.o:Dataset.cpp:(.text$_ZNSt15__new_allocatorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEE8allocateEyPKv[_ZNSt15__new_allocatorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEE8allocateEyPKv]+0x4a): undefined reference to `std::__throw_bad_array_new_length()'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dataset.o:Dataset.cpp:(.text$_ZNSt15__new_allocatorISt10_List_nodeIiEE8allocateEyPKv[_ZNSt15__new_allocatorISt10_List_nodeIiEE8allocateEyPKv]+0x4a): undefined reference to `std::__throw_bad_array_new_length()'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dataset.o:Dataset.cpp:(.text$_ZNSt15__new_allocatorISt10_List_nodeINSt7__cxx114listIiSaIiEEEEE8allocateEyPKv[_ZNSt15__new_allocatorISt10_List_nodeINSt7__cxx114listIiSaIiEEEEE8allocateEyPKv]+0x4a): undefined reference to `std::__throw_bad_array_new_length()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

any one can help? Should I need to upgrade g++ to higher version? Thank you.

How did you compile Dataset.cpp to get Dataset.o?  Did you  use the same compiler/toolchain?

Dataset.o is a provided library; I just use it to compile my program

Looks like a broken compiler. Maybe Strawberry Perl in PATH causes interference, remove it from there.

@HolyBlackCat I have removed it, but error still occur

Please show the new error message. The one you have in the question mentions StPerl...

Dataset.o is a provided library; I just use it to compile my program  Was the provided Dataset.o also compiled with g++ 10.3?

The paths suggest that you really have g++ 8.3.0 (or that Dataset.o was compiled with that version, not sure).

hello, I just updated the error message #HolyBlackCat, #Yksisarvinen. @Eljay I am not sure.

The object file was compiled against a newer libstdc++ version than you have installed. You need a newer libstdc++ version which comes with a newer GCC version (>=11 I think). Also, in general, it is a bad idea to use a precompilied object file like this. Instead compile everything from source yourself. Otherwise you must make sure that you use the same compiler (e.g. GCC), same standard library implementation (e.g. libstdc++), same target architecture and some other configurations of the compiler and you need to consider ABI compatibility between versions as well (as the issue here).

The whole set of conditions you need to keep track of is complicated and usually it is just easier to compile everything with the same compiler setup or follow instructions for supported compiler setups by the library author. If you have an ABI mismatch it may fail to compile or compile and have subtle bugs that are hard to detect.

You need a newer libstdc++ version which comes with a newer GCC version (>=11 I think) @user17732522 can you suggest me a way to use newer libstdc++ version?

@hoango27 You need to install a MinGW distribution (i.e. GCC distribution for Windows) with (I think) at least version 11.0, but I don't use GCC on Windows, so I don't know which ones are available.
